# How to make RuboCop inspect a file in a folder that starts with dot

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I want to run [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) for [VisualEditor](https://github.com/wikimedia/VisualEditor) repository. At the moment, the only Ruby file I could find in the repository is [.docs/CustomTags.rb](https://github.com/wikimedia/VisualEditor/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=in%3Apath%20rb).

```
$ find . | grep rb
./.docs/CustomTags.rb
```

If I run only `rubocop`, it does not find any files:

```
$ rubocop
Inspecting 0 files
0 files inspected, no offenses detected
```

I guess it ignores files in folders that start with dot (`.docs`).

RuboCop documentation on [including files](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#includingexcluding-files) says:

> If you'd like it to check other files you'll need to manually pass
>   them in, or to add entries for them under AllCops/Include.

If I provide path to the file from the command line, RuboCop finds the file:

```
$ rubocop .docs/CustomTags.rb 
Inspecting 1 file
W
(...)
1 file inspected, 26 offenses detected
```

Our continuous integration just runs `rubocop` for the repository, so I can not provide path to the file from the command line. I have to use `AllCops/Include`, but I can not figure out how to do it.

If I create a `.rubocop.yml` in the root of the repository:

```
AllCops:
  Include:
    - '.docs/CustomTags.rb'
```

and run Rubocop, it does not find the file:

```
$ rubocop
Inspecting 0 files
0 files inspected, no offenses detected
```

I have tried several variations of the `.rubocop.yml` file, including:

```
AllCops:
  Include:
    - '**/CustomTags.rb'
```

and

```
AllCops:
  Include:
    - '.docs/**/*'
```

But none of them are finding the file.

Comment: Also reported here: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/1401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a [bug in RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/1401). It is fixed now, but the gem with the fix is not released yet.

Comment: Looks like it was fixed in Rubocop version 0.27.1.